# Custom resolver React-hook-form

Tags: react-hook-form

Can't get errors from resolver using react-hook-form custom resolvers. Trying to validate some fields dynamically. But if I submit form I can get errors fields

```js
export const customResolver = (parameters) => {
  return (values, _context, { fields, names }) => {
    const transformedParameters = transformParameters(parameters);
    const paramsIds = getParamsIds(transformedParameters);
    const { name, value } = Object.values(fields)[0];
    let errors = {};

    if (names && names[0].length <= 3) {
      // Validate single field

      const textRequired = transformedParameters
        .find(({ id }) => id === name)
        .values.find(({ name: valueName }) => value === valueName).textRequired;
      if (textRequired && !values[`${names} commentary`]) {
        errors = {
          [`${names} commentary`]: {
            type: "required",
            message: "Поле необходимо заполнить!",
          },
        };
      }
    } else {
      // Validate onSubmit method

      errors = Object.entries(values).reduce((acc, [id, fieldValue]) => {
        if (paramsIds.includes(id) && !fieldValue) {
          return {
            ...acc,
            [id]: { type: "required", message: "Поле необходимо заполнить!" },
          };
        }
        return acc;
      }, {});
    }
    return { values, errors };
  };
};
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: what exactly is the issue? validation is not triggered when changing values?
You can try passing mode:"onChange"

`const methods = useForm ({ defaultValues, resolver, mode: 'onChange'}); `